# HTML/CSS font-weight difficulty

Tags: html, css

To begin the `font-weight` for me is not working(i dont understand how it works),
**HERE IS THE CODE**:

```
.pimg{
    font-weight: 10;
}
```

```
<div class="imgp">
    <img class="fleming"src="https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/183FB/production/_113832399_aleksandarflemingsasuprugom1954.jpg" alt="Alexander Fleming and his wife">
   <p class="pimg">The man who saved millions of people, Alexander Fleming</p>
</div>
```

The project I'm working on need the lighter letters and the font weight doesen't change no matter what (BOLD is working so the class is working), when I put the weight to lighter,1,10,20,30... it doesen't work can anyone elaborate?

Comment: `font-weight: 10;` doesn't exist. use `font-weight: 100;` , `200`... `lighter` etc,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: Also, some fonts may not have all the values...  e.g. "Arial" has 400 (regular) and 700 (bold), but there is a separate "Arial Black" font which has a value of 900 that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The font weight isn't changing because it's already at it's lowest setting for that particular **font-family**. You should try switching your font, if you need something thinner. You can do a web search for **"web safe fonts"** to find a list of font-families you can readily use. I would suggest trying "Garamond," as it looks fairly thin and becomes even thinner when '*italicized*.'